# Residues and Laurent expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How can I prove that the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ when $f(z)$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z=z_0$ is given by:
$$
a_{-1}=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}\left[(z-z_0)^mf(z)\right]_{z=z_0}
$$
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=-m}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$ be the Laurent expansion of $f$ at $z_0$. Then $g(z)=(z-z_0)^mf(z)$ is holomorphic around $z_0$ and its Taylor expansion at $z_0$ is $g(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n-m}(z-z_0)^n$. Therefore, $a_{-1}=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}g^{(m-1)}(z_0)$, and the conclusion follows.

Comment: You mean $g(z)=(z-z_0)^m f(z)$

Comment: @M.Strochyk: Thank you for correcting this typo.

Comment: @richard and putting $n-m=x$ we can find any $a_x$ using $$a_x=\frac{1}{(m+x)!}g^{(m+x)(z_0)}$$.
Is that correct?

Comment: @IvanLerner: Yes, you are right!